# How get User Information from SQL Server with identity

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC. I want to get User Information from SQL Server with Identity.

This is my AdminController:

```
private ApplicationDbContext _application;
public AdminController (ApplicationDbContext application)
{
    _application = application;
}

public IActionResult ListUsers()
{
    return View(_application.Users.ToList());
}
```

My View:

```
{
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)</td>
}
```

but it shows me that Error.

> "InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebAppMVC.ApplicationUser]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo , please check the difference on yours and make modification :

*DbContext*

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbcontext;

    public HomeController( ApplicationDbContext dbcontext)
    {
        _dbcontext = dbcontext;
    }

    public IActionResult ListUsers()
    {
        return View(_dbcontext.Users.ToList());
    }
}
```

*View*

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCIdentityDemo3_1.Models.ApplicationUser>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tnx.It works.but when I want to login again it shows this Error   /InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context./

Comment: @Mohadese99 , what's your DbContext and Startup? When extending IdenityUser and  with `ApplicationUser` , you  should update your identity service registration in startup as follows: `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();`

Answer (score 1):

Your ApplicationUser inherit from identityUser?

Check if the view response is the same as the view model